# How to achieve synchronous mechanism in wso2 mi using iterator mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am dynamically reading APIs from DB and iterating those APIs using the iterator mediator and calling endpoint, but here each API response is input to the subsequent API, so I need to apply a synchronous mechanism, how can I achieve this in the iterator mediator ; but by using blocking=true in call mediator I am achieving ,but the response of all APIs I am not able to aggregate. that aggregate mediator does not work after that in the execution.

I need a solution to achieve a synchronous mechanism and be able to use each API response to subsequent API and finally all APIs need to aggregate.